# Show only valid actions on file input click on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile-safari, forms, mobile-chrome

I have a `input type=file` and I want when user click on it to show only valid actions for documents. I don't want pictures or videos.

My file tag is:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.txt,.odt,.wps"/>
```

With this configuration when user click on it on ios safari will display a menu with:

- Take a Photo or Video
- Photo Library
- iCloud
- More

and on Android devices will show something like this:

- Camera
- Camcorder
- Documents
- Voice Recorder
- other, depends what's installed on device.

What I want is to have on iOS only the options iCloud and More and on Android only Documents or other where you can find documents. I want to exclude to take a picture/video or to choose from photo library.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can dictate what kind of document you're willing to accept, but you cannot dictate what the file upload box actually looks like on a particular browser/OS.

Clearly it would be sensible for the browser not to show "Camera" or "Take a Photo" when the photo produced in that manner wouldn't ultimately be accepted, but that level of intelligence just isn't baked in... yet.